# Выравнивание блока по центру без влияния полосок скроллбара

Tags: вёрстка, css

Всем привет. Есть маленькая деталь, которую хочу реализовать. Как известно, если сайт больше высоты экрана, то появляется справа скролл, который двигает сайт (он центрирован с шириной 1000px). Увидел, что такая фишка есть и у вк.ком

То есть, сайт находится как блок, четко по центру, шириной 1000px и на него не должен влиять скролл справа, как при появление, так и при исчезновении. Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Наваял [пример](http://jsfiddle.net/E5psm/2/).

В нём блок .window эмулирует окно браузера. Код определения ширины скролла грязный, но ничего чище и работающего в интернетах не нашёл.

Осталось дописать определение скролла на странице (есть или нет) и код из примера можно использовать после небольших корректировок.

Работает он так: если скролла нет, то вычисляется возможная ширина скролла и центрированный блок смещается на половину ширины скролла влево (для этого нужно прописать этому блоку `position: relative;`)